# How to get each two elements in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach

I have XML like this:

```
<image>
  <image url="img1.jpg" />
  <image url="img2.jpg" />
  <image url="img3.jpg" />
  <image url="img4.jpg" />
  <image url="img5.jpg" />
</image>
```

and i need to make HTML like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="img1.jpg" />
    <img src="img2.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="img3.jpg" />
    <img src="img4.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="img5.jpg" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

How I can split subnodes to make this HTML?

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/image">
    <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="image[position() mod 2 = 1]">
            <li>
                <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::image[1]" />
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="image">
    <img src="{@url}" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

In **XSLT 2.0**, you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="/image">
    <ul>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="image" group-starting-with="image[position() mod 2 = 1]">
            <li>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="image">
    <img src="{@url}" />
</xsl:template>
```